# How do I select only p tags that come after an h4 tag - but are not children in Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I can use either Xpath or CSS.

I tried:

```
my_page.xpath('//h4/p')
```

But that seems to look for just `p` tags that are children of `h4`.

The HTML structure I am parsing looks like this:

```
<h4 class="ban">Mon May 28</h4>
<p><a href="http://phoenix.craigslist.org/cph/cpg/3043067349.html">.Net/Java Developers</a> - <font size="-1"> (phoenix )</font></p>
<p><a href="http://phoenix.craigslist.org/cph/cpg/3043066699.html">QA and Business Analysts</a> - <font size="-1"> (Phoenix Metro)</font></p>
```

There are other `p` & `a` elements on the page...but basically what I want to do is associate the words within the `h4` tag with the links that come after it on the page (not nested within it).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my_page.css("h4 + p")` should work.

`+` is the [adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors).

Comment: Perfect, that works. Thanks! Btw, what's the link for the w3 docs for xpath?